# ovirt noVNC console error : Something went wrong, connection is closed

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, centos8, ovirt

Context :
oVirt 4.4.9.3-1.el8
glusterfs 8.6
Self-hosted engine

Problem:
Since I update my certificates (with engine-setup) because of the warning that my certs
will expire soon, I can't open the noVNC console anymore.

In the logs on engine, I have these :
in `/var/log/messages` :

```
ovsdb-server[510110]: ovs|04628|jsonrpc|WARN|ssl:[::ffff:<ip_node_1>]:51214: receive
error: Protocol error
ovsdb-server[510110]: ovs|04629|reconnect|WARN|ssl:[::ffff:<ip_node_1>]:51214:
connection dropped (Protocol error)
journal[516217]: 2022-12-21 11:31:27,800+0100 ovirt-websocket-proxy: INFO msg:871 handler
exception: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown
(_ssl.c:897)
ovirt-websocket-proxy.py[509812]: ovirt-websocket-proxy[516217] INFO msg:871 handler
exception: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown
(_ssl.c:897)
ovsdb-server[510110]: ovs|04632|stream_ssl|WARN|SSL_accept: error:1417C086:SSL
routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

in `/var/log/openvswitch/ovsdb-server-sb.log` :

```
2022-12-21T10:31:22.540Z|04626|stream_ssl|WARN|SSL_accept: error:1417C086:SSL
routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
2022-12-21T10:31:22.541Z|04627|jsonrpc|WARN|Dropped 1 log messages in last 8 seconds (most
recently, 8 seconds ago) due to excessive rate
2022-12-21T10:31:22.541Z|04628|jsonrpc|WARN|ssl:[::ffff:<ip_node_1>]:51214: receive
error: Protocol error
2022-12-21T10:31:22.542Z|04629|reconnect|WARN|ssl:[::ffff:<ip_node_1>]:51214:
connection dropped (Protocol error)
```

I've tried these commands in [this link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6877501)

```
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/bin/pki-enroll-pkcs12.sh --name="ovirt-provider-ovn"
--password=mypass --subject="<subject_engine>" --keep-key
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/bin/pki-enroll-pkcs12.sh --name="ovn-ndb"
--password=mypass --subject="<subject_engine>" --keep-key
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/bin/pki-enroll-pkcs12.sh --name="ovn-sdb"
--password=mypass --subject="<subject_engine>" --keep-key
systemctl restart ovirt-provider-ovn.service
systemctl restart ovn-northd.service
```

Still not work, so I've seen that some certificates was still not renewed :

```
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/bin/pki-enroll-pkcs12.sh --name="vmconsole-proxy-helper"
--password=mypass --subject="<subject_engine>" --keep-key
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/bin/pki-enroll-pkcs12.sh --name="vmconsole-proxy-host"
--password=mypass --subject="<subject_engine>" --keep-key
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/bin/pki-enroll-pkcs12.sh --name="vmconsole-proxy-user"
--password=mypass --subject="<subject_engine>" --keep-key
```

And restart every ovirt services.

But it still does not work better.

I don't see any other unvalid certificates in /etc/pki/ovirt-engine/certs/, so I
don't know which certificate is invalid for ovsdb.

What I've missed ?